# Modifying an array keeping a copy

Tags: python, arrays

I wanted to modify an array but keeping an original version of it so I coded:

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
b = a
a.append("g")
```

I expected:

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]
b = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
```

But I retrieved:

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]
b = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g"]
```

It does not matter if I append a value to `a` or `b`, I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
b = []
b.extend(a)
print (b)
a.append("g")
print(a)
```

Output:

> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
>
> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

Comment: "b = a" does not do what you think, only a reference is copied. You can either use  list.extend() or list.copy(). They both get the job done

Comment: Caveat: If you have a nested list like `a = [[0], [1], [2]]` and copy with `extend` you might run into problems. After `a[0].append("g")` you'll get `[[0, 'g'], [1], [2]]` for `b`.

Comment: understood. But OP did not specify nature of the list. OP has posted a regular list